# Declare Stringvar variable as class variable in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, initialization, class-variables

I want to initiate a class variable in order to pass it to another class. This variable has to be a `StringVar` variable as I want to use it for an `Entry` function of `Tkinter`. What I have done so far is this:

```
class ClassA:
    var1 = StringVar()
    def __init__(self,master):
        entry1 = Entry(master, textvariable = var1)

root = Tk()
my_gui = ClassA(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, it gives the message:

> `StringVar instance has no attribute '_tk'.`

This can be solved by adding `Tk()` before the declaration of `StringVar` but this produces a new window when I start my app. Is there a way to declare it without having to add the `Tk()` line? I can't figure out why this happens as I initiate `Tk()` outside the class.

Comment: Why exactly do you need it to be class variable as opposed to an instance variable?

Comment: _"I want to initiate a class variable in order to pass it to another class."_ - it doesn't have to be a class variable in order for you to do that.

Comment: How else can I know the value of a StringVar from another class without it being a class variable?

Answer (score 2):

Non-definition lines under a `class` declaration are read as soon as they're reached, and at the time at which the `var1 = StringVar()` there is no `Tk` instance, hence the error.

You can instead assign `var1` class variable inside a method in the class, `__init__` perhaps. Replace:

```
class ClassA:
    var1 = StringVar()
    def __init__(self,master):
        entry1 = Entry(master, textvariable = var1)
```

with:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self,master):
        entry1 = Entry(master)
        ClassA.var1 = StringVar()
        entry1['textvariable'] = ClassA.var1
```

A complete example:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, master):
        entry1 = tk.Entry(master)
        ClassA.var1 = tk.StringVar()
        entry1['textvariable'] = ClassA.var1
        ClassA.var1.set('"asd"')
        print("[Inside call], it is: {}".format(entry1.get()))


root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = ClassA(root)
print("[Outside call], it is: {}".format(ClassA.var1.get()))
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using this example, when I want to use the StringVar from another class, it gives me the error: AttributeError: class ClassA has no attribute 'var1'.

Comment: @tzoukritzou With the example above, there _has_ to be an instance of `ClassA` such as `my_gui`.